# How to fill in array gaps when an element is removed?

Tags: c, arrays

Lets say I have an array of pointers to some object.

```
foo* bar[256];
```

and lets say it contains a list of all the blitted(blitting) textures to my buffer. I then request to take something off the array via deletion, and the thing I am taking off is NOT at the end, right. So there is an empty sort of gap in the array

```
(filled memory), (empty), (filled memory), (filled memory), etc
```

While I guess in this example it doesn't really matter, but how would I take every entry in the array that is ahead of the empty space and sort of press it back so the empty space is on the end?

Sorry about the poor wording, friends!

Answer (score 3):

Shifting all the items takes time. If the order of the items doesnt matter I suggest shift only the last item to fill the gap and hold a size int to specify the occupied size.

You should hold it in a struct

```
typedef struct{
 int occupied;
 foo* bar[256];
}
```

lets say we want to delete the k'th cell:

```
delete(myStruct.bar[k]);
myStruct.bar[k] = myStruct.bar[myStruct.occupied--];
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say for example, that you know `bar[128]` is empty.

The following loop will shift all the elements after `bar[128]` to the left by one, and thus leave the empty space at the end:

```
for (int k = 129; k < 128; k++) {
   bar[k-1] = bar[k];
}
```

It is definitely possible to generalize this to more than one gap in your array, but that becomes a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i, j;
for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
    if (!(bar[i])) {
        for (j=i; j<255; j++) {
            bar[j] = bar[j+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to do that than going through each element in the array that'S above the gap and sort it. If this happens very often, it can become a performance issue. Maybe you should try another data structure, like a linked list. There each element has a pointer to it's next element. Now when you remove one element in the middle of the list, you just have to point the element before the removed one to the element that was next to the removed one - that's it, now your list is sorted again.